# Put button in div class="g-recaptcha"

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

Is it possible to put some buttons on the right from g-recaptcha? for example like this: [image: preview]

Comment: of course, but this question is too broad.  Maybe put in some code you tried, or a jsfiddle link where you are testing it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3heL9k8s/ this is my code

Comment: Do you want to bring the send button next to captcha or a new button?

Comment: thanks, i've dealt with this, its my code now: https://jsfiddle.net/sery3jqL/

Comment: you may use bootstrap input-group as well. https://jsfiddle.net/o2matyzj/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added to your code;

```
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcnqWUUAAAAAEc8mxt6aE1GIvasVmPqfy-cgYFK"</div>
    <button class="added">Oooh look, a button!</button>
    <button name="add" type="submit" id="napBUT" name="btn" class="btn btn-danger btn form-control">send</button>
```

Apply `width:304px;float:left`to `.g-recaptcha` and `width:calc(100% - 304px);margin-top:0;` to `.added`